# Netavis won't start

Tags: permissions, centos5

I have Netavis Observer 4.3 installed on CentOS 5.11. Users connected over network can login and everything works fine, but client on server won't start because of some permissions error. It says:

> The installer has tried to find a suitable place on ypour computer to install the product, but either it did not have enough permissions or found too little available disk space.
>
> Directories used:
>
> /home/view
>
> Please correct the problem and restart the instalation.

I checked disk space, and have enough free space. It's some kind of permissions error. I tried to change permissions in this path, but with no success, it's displays the same message over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to repair this. First, when none of methods worked, I changed home folder of `view` user (whis is responded to show client on server) to `view.old` and then create new folder called `view`. Moved everything to new folder, and it's working now.